# Mistake in Multivariable Transformation

Tags: probability, self-study, multivariate-distribution

The answer is $\frac{19}{24}$ but I don't know where is my mistake. The question is this.

Let $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} x+y, \quad 0<x<1, 0<y<1 \\ 0, \quad \quad \quad \text{elsewhere}\end{cases},$$
What is the probability of $\Pr(X<2Y)$?

Let $V = X$ and $W = X - 2Y$. Hence we have Jacobi matrix $$J = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$ and $\det(J) = \frac{1}{2}$.

So we have
$$
f_{X,Y}(x(v,w),y(v,w)) = \begin{cases} v + \left(\frac{v-w}{2}\right) |J| = \frac{1}{4} \left(3v - w\right), \quad 0<v<1, v-2<w<v \\ 0, \quad \quad \quad \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}
$$
Hence we have,
$$
f_{W}(w) = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{4} \left(3v - w\right) \, dv = \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{3}{2} - w \right)
$$
Lastly we have
\begin{align*}
\Pr(X < 2Y) = \Pr(X-2Y <0) &= \Pr(W < 0) \\
&= \int_{-2}^{0} f_W(w) \, dw \\
&= \int_{-2}^{0} \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{3}{2} - w \right) \, dw \\
&= \frac{1}{4}  \left[ \frac{3}{2}w - \frac{w^2}{2} | {}_{w=-2}^{w=0} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{3}{2} - \left(-\frac{4}{2}\right) \right) = \frac{7}{8} 
\end{align*}

Comment: I would have thought $\int\limits_{x=0}^1\,\,\int\limits_{y=x/2}^1 (x+y)\, dy \, dx$ might be easier

Comment: thank you. I feel dumb to use transformation